# Create index to text type column

Tags: mysql, sql

How to create index for text data type column in mysql efficiently,for a table having more than 10 L rows (each row has 500 chars).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using innodb, you should create a `FULLTEXT` index.

> `FULLTEXT` indexes are created on text-based columns (`CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, or `TEXT` columns) to help speed up queries and DML operations on data contained within those columns, omitting any words that are defined as stopwords.

Please see the [MySQL FULLTEXT documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html).

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE opening_lines (
   id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   opening_line TEXT(500),
   author VARCHAR(200),
   title VARCHAR(200),
   FULLTEXT idx (opening_line)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: I'm using mysql 5.5 and engine is innodb. mysql can't provide FULLTEXT idx  option in 5.5, what should i do?

Comment: It does exist in 5.5, see [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables. (In MySQL 5.6 and up, they can also be used with InnoDB tables.) Full-text indexes can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.